# running at vs running toward

Tags: difference

> The drunk man started running at/toward the bouncer.

Does one of "at" and "toward" more clearly than the other indicate a hostile intention?

Answer (score 2):

"Running towards" only indicates the direction. It doesn't indicate any intention (hostile or otherwise). It doesn't even indicate the intention to reach the bouncer.

"Running to" indictes the intention to reach the destination. But doesn't suggest a hostile intent

"Running at" is nearly always used to describe an attack.

> The dog ran at the girl and bit her on various parts of her body. ([source](https://coventryobserver.co.uk/news/coventry-woman-whose-bulldog-savaged-young-girl-in-street-defies-court-and-avoids-jail/))

> Lidgett had ran at the man, who was walking towards his car, and punched him to the head three times ([source](https://www.chad.co.uk/news/crime/mansfield-man-may-have-had-his-drinks-spiked-after-unprovoked-christmas-day-attack-town-car-park-3006729))

> If there's a man pointing a gun at you we don't want you running at the man pointing the gun, that would be crazy. ([source](https://news.sky.com/story/public-should-get-involved-to-help-officers-under-attack-says-met-police-chief-11571365))

> So Sis Cow backed up again and ran at the tree with her horns down. SMACK! She butted the tree as hard as she could. (*Brer Rabbit fools Sis Cow*)

"Running at (somebody)" means attacking them at a run.